# BigQuery alias case and use in where clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Can someone help me understand what's wrong with this query?

BigQuery is showing an error:

> Error: Unrecognized name: case1 at [...]

```
SELECT
  col1,
  CASE
    WHEN col2 IN ('text1') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END as case1
  CASE
    WHEN col2 IN ('text2') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END as case2
FROM `dataset.tablename`
WHERE case1 = 1 OR case2 = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  col1,
  CASE
    WHEN col2 IN ('text') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END as case1
FROM `dataset.tablename`
WHERE CASE
    WHEN col2 IN ('text') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END = 1
```

You can't query on an alias in the same statement